# Can I create recaptcha keys good for any domain?

Tags: recaptcha-enterprise

I'm creating a set of keys for our apps up on Azure where we have 2 domains (production and dev slots). But we also need keys for all the developers when they run on their system.

Is there a way to create a set of keys good for any domain so we set those in the appsettings.json (which we override on Azure) and then any developer on any system can use it.